# Is NativeScript compatible with Angular4?

Tags: angular, nativescript

Is [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) compatible with [Angular4](https://angular.io/)?

[Angular4](https://angular.io/) is going to be released soon and I am not seeing any details on the compatibility of [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) and [Angular4](https://angular.io/). Does anyone else have any details on this compatibility?

Not seeing anything on their [roadmap](https://www.nativescript.org/roadmap) regarding the compatibility.

Comment: as this post, i seem NativeScript will compatible with Angular 4. Because v4 will backwards compatible with v2 http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html

Comment: It will happen for sure. The nativescript team isn't stopping development on working with angular. They usually have close communication with the angular team to work together. so I doubt it stops anytime soon :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular4 is supported in NativeScript. This [article](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-supports-angular-4) talks about the compatibility.

---

**Old response below.**

A recent [article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3168721/javascript/nativescript-30-lines-up-release-with-angular-4.html) published, talks about [NativeScript3](https://www.nativescript.org/) having support for [Angular4](https://angular.io/).

Looks like [NativeScript3](https://www.nativescript.org/) may be releasing this version in April, according to the [article](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3168721/javascript/nativescript-30-lines-up-release-with-angular-4.html).